# Amplitude of Sine wave

Tags: trigonometry

How can I alter amplitude of a sine wave, such that it is in the range of [-1,30]?

$y = A\sin(\theta t + \phi)$. I want $A$ to be 30 and $-A$ to be -1.

Comment: $14.5 \sin(\theta t+\phi)+14.5$.

Comment: $A$ can not be simultaneously $30$ and $1$.

Comment: Sin wave go up and comes down. So I want the up bit to be around 30 and down bit to be around -1. The closest I came is by using `x=(14.5*(sin(t/(n-1)*20*pi-1)+rnorm(n)*0.3)+9.5)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total range of your wave is $30 - (-1) = 31$, so you need the amplitude to be half this, $\frac{31}{2}$.  The horizontal line of symmetry should be halfway between the maximum and minimum, so at $\frac{30 + (-1)}{2} = \frac{29}{2}$.

$$ \frac{31}{2} \sin(\theta t + \phi) + \frac{29}{2} $$